# Trying to create a random joke generator that chooses between two joke setups and fills them up randomly

Tags: python

Okay so I am trying to make code like this work:

```
import random

joke = ["random.choice(x) + 'is the type of guy to' random.choice(y) 'during a school shooting'", "'lego' + random.choice(z)"]
x = ["Porkus", "Celery", "Gartic Phone", "Hououin"]
y = ["hit the griddy", "american all over everyone", "distract the shooter by shouting bingus"]
z = ["ninjago 1989 conspiracy", "conspiracy", "borkus junior", "holocaust", "Kurisu"]

print(random.choice(joke))
```

My goal is for it to print something like either

Porkus is the type of guy to hit the griddy during a school shooting

or

lego ninjago 1989 conspiracy

so essentially I want it to choose to print either of these
`random.choice(x) + 'is the type of guy to' random.choice(y) 'during a school shooting', "'lego' + random.choice(z)`

and I want it to then take from the lists to fill in x y and z for each of the jokes

I just tried to run this and other iterations but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are about there, although your formatting of the string is causing issues. For simplicity I used string formatting (the f before the "") to access variables directly in the string.

```
import random
x = ["Porkus", "Celery", "Gartic Phone", "Hououin"] 
y = ["hit the griddy", "american all over everyone", "distract the shooter by shouting bingus"] 
z = ["ninjago 1989 conspiracy", "conspiracy", "borkus junior", "holocaust", "Kurisu"]

joke = [f"{random.choice(x)} is the type of guy to {random.choice(y)} during a school shooting", f"lego {random.choice(z)}"] 
print(random.choice(joke))
```

Keep in mind this sets the strings in the list at runtime, so if you tried getting the values from the `joke` list several times within the same run they wouldn't change. Also notice that `joke` is initialized after `x`, `y,` and `z`. This is because those 3 needs to be initialized before they can be accessed. Side note, if you plan to do more in-depth code in the future, its good to pick more descriptive names.

Comment: The last line chooses a joke from 1-item list "randomly".

Comment: its a two item list @KlasŠ.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are putting the whole generated string into a list called "joke". This list will only have 1 value in it, so Im confused what exactly the goal is here.

IF you just want to print 1 joke by choosing random words between from the three lists x,y and z, your logical approach is fine, and simply following Shorn's [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75456367/14864866) here will work for you

in python, double or single quotes translates to strings. Therefore this code will specifically Only print out the text written inside the quotes. all the "Choice.random"s you have used inside the quotes won't actually execute as code, but simply just be taken as a string.

Your Code :

```
joke = ["random.choice(x) + 'is the type of guy to' random.choice(y) 'during a school shooting'", "'lego' + random.choice(z)"]

x = ["Porkus", "Celery", "Gartic Phone", "Hououin"]

y = ["hit the griddy", "american all over everyone", "distract the shooter by shouting bingus"] 

z = ["ninjago 1989 conspiracy", "conspiracy", "borkus junior", "holocaust", "Kurisu"]
print(joke)
```

The issue comes down to your syntax. You have written the joke text inside double quotes (") here

```
joke = ["random.choice(x) + 'is the type of guy to' random.choice(y) 'during a school shooting'", "'lego' + random.choice(z)"]
```

This will treat "random.choice()" as a string, and will not actually execute it. So you must keep the random.choice() call outside of the quotes ("....")

Furthermore, The variables x,y and z are defined after you try to call them. This doesn't work in python as its an interpreted language, not a compiled one. So you have to move these declarations above

As you seem to be trying to get multiple "jokes" stored inside, may I suggest creating a loop and storing the jokes one after the other into the list like this ?

```
number_of_jokes = 10
jokes = []
x = ["Porkus", "Celery", "Gartic Phone", "Hououin"]
y = ["hit the griddy", "american all over everyone", "distract the shooter by shouting bingus"] 
z = ["ninjago 1989 conspiracy", "conspiracy", "borkus junior", "holocaust", "Kurisu"]

for i in range (number_of_jokes) :
    jokes += [random.choice(x) + ' is the type of guy to ' + random.choice(y) + ' during a school shooting lego ' + random.choice(z)]

for j in range (len(jokes)) :
    print(jokes[j])
```